# convert format of excel sales data to importable SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with data in it that looks like this (the values are quantities of sales):

[example sales spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYKyP.png)

However, I need the format to look like this so I can import it into a SQL  table we have set up for sales:

[Ideal spreadsheet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jycYU.png)

Is this possible? Apologies for any formatting issues, this is my first time posting so I hope it all makes sense! :)

Comment: UNION ALL comes to mind.

Comment: Hi @Scott Craner. The question you linked has answered mine! Thanks for your help and apologises for any inconvenience caused